# Script for updating an Oracle database

Tags: sql, perl, oracle

I have the following piece of Perl script for updating an Oracle database. It's working perfectly fine, but I want to know how I can simplify this script.

```
use DBI;
my $dbh;
my $bad_form = "text.txt";

open (OUT, $bad_form) or die "Could not open $bad_form";
while (<OUT>){
   chomp $_;
   my ($item_id, $description, $form_id_1, $form_id_3) = split(/\|/, $_);

   my $new_form_id_1 = form_1($form_id_1);
   my $new_form_id_3 = form_3($form_id_3);

   if ( $new_form_id_1 ne 'null' ){
        my $sql = "update item_table set form_id_1 = '$new_form_id_1' where item_id = '$item_id'";
        my $item = $dbh->prepare($sql) or (log_error("Couldn't prepare statement: " . $dbh->errstr) and return 2);
        $item->execute() or (log_error("Couldn't execute statement: " . $item->errstr) and return 2);
   }else{
        $form_id_1 = "correct value";
        $new_form_id_1 = "no updated";
}

   if ( $new_form_id_3 ne 'null' ){
        my $sql = "update item_table set form_id_3 = '$new_form_id_3' where item_id = '$item_id'";
        my $item = $dbh->prepare($sql) or (log_error("Couldn't prepare statement: " . $dbh->errstr) and return 2);
        $item->execute() or (log_error("Couldn't execute statement: " . $item->errstr) and return 2);

   }else{
        $form_id_3 = "correct value";
        $new_form_id_3 = "no updated";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Some basic refactoring, and using `?` placeholders in sql queries,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
my $dbh;
my $bad_form = "text.txt";

sub prepare_execute {
    my ($sql, $values, $dbh) = @_;

    my $item = $dbh->prepare($sql) or do {
        log_error("Couldn't prepare statement: " . $dbh->errstr);
        die;
    };
    $item->execute(@$values) or do {
        log_error("Couldn't execute statement: " . $item->errstr);
        die;
    };
    return 1;
}

open (my $OUT, "<", $bad_form) or die "$! $bad_form";
while (<$OUT>) {
   chomp $_;
   my ($item_id, $description, $form_id_1, $form_id_3) = split(/\|/, $_);

   my $new_form_id_1 = form_1($form_id_1);
   my $new_form_id_3 = form_3($form_id_3);

   if ( $new_form_id_1 ne 'null' ){
        my $sql = "update item_table set form_id_1 =? where item_id =?";
        eval { prepare_execute($sql, [$new_form_id_1, $item_id], $dbh) }
          or return 2;
   }
   else {
        $form_id_1 = "correct value";
        $new_form_id_1 = "no updated";
    }

   if ( $new_form_id_3 ne 'null' ) {
        my $sql = "update item_table set form_id_3 =? where item_id =?";
        eval { prepare_execute($sql, [$new_form_id_3, $item_id], $dbh) }
          or return 2;
   }
   else {
        $form_id_3 = "correct value";
        $new_form_id_3 = "no updated";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Happy things

- Thanks for `use strict`.  That is smart.
- I'm also a fan of the 3-argument form of `open`.  That can avoid a few subtle bugs/holes.
- Using a scalar for your filehandle.

## Suggestions

Some areas which could be improved:

### use perltidy

Your indentation is inconsistent.  [Perltidy](http://perltidy.sourceforge.net/) will reformat your code for you with a variety of customization options so it can look as you prefer.  [Here](https://github.com/chicks-net/chicks-home/blob/master/.perltidyrc) are my settings if you'd like a starting point.  (Tabs and cuddled elses ftw, but ymmv!)

### use single quotes for most literals

If you are using a literal that doesn't require anything special like *interpolation* of variables it is safer to put it in single quotes.  For instance I used to see a lot of

```
 my $email = "foo@example.com";
```

Where perl goes and gets confused because there is no `@example` array defined (hopefully).  SO by using single quotes which don't interpolate or do anything else surprising:

```
 my $email = 'foo@example.com';
```

### using placeholders for building SQL queries

I spent a lot of time hand-molding SQL queries in Perl, but it is ultimately safer to use placeholders for your queries as [mpapec demonstrated](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/149864/89257).  This will avoid SQL injection attacks and other types of crashes.

### simplification

We don't see the definition of `form1()` and `form3()` but if they're under your control you could have them return more useful information.

- One way would be to have it return `'correct value'` and then branch on that.
- Another way and my preference would be to have it update both values like so:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/perl

  use strict;
  use warnings;

  sub form1 {
      my ($id) = @_;

      if ($id < 10) {
          return ('not updated', 'correct value');
      } else {
          return ($id*10, $id);
      }
  }

  foreach my $form_id (1..20) {
      print "$form_id:\n";

      my $new_form_id;
      ($new_form_id,$form_id) = form1($form_id);

      unless ($new_form_id eq 'not updated') {
          print "in unless\n";
      }
  }
  ```